# Accessing every attribute of every node in an XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working with an XElement object that sometimes contains nodes with empty or whitespace xmlns attributes (for example, in the emptyNsTag node of the example XML. What I want to do is remove all such attributes from the XElement, so the example:

```
<header xmlns="some uri">
<tag1 xmlns="another uri">
    <tag2>
        <tag3>a value</tag3>
        <tag4 attr="foo">bar</tag4>
        <tag5>something else</tag5>
        <tag6 xmlns="a third uri">another value</tag6>
    </tag2>
    </tag1>
    <emptyNsTag xmlns=" " attr2="something different" attr3="0">not important</emptyNsTag>
</header>
```

would be converted to:

```
<header xmlns="some uri">
    <tag1 xmlns="another uri">
    <tag2>
        <tag3>a value</tag3>
        <tag4 attr="foo">bar</tag4>
        <tag5>something else</tag5>
        <tag6 xmlns="a third uri">another value</tag6>
    </tag2>
    </tag1>
    <emptyNsTag attr2="something different" attr3="0">not important</emptyNsTag>
</header>
```

However, I haven't been able to find an efficient way to access all the attributes in the whole document tree to check if they are empty or whitespace.

I tried using `xml.Attributes().Where(attr => attr.Name.LocalName == "xmlns" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr.Value)).Remove();` to filter them out, but the Attributes() method only seems to return the attributes of the top level node (`xmlns="some uri"` in the example XML).

There are other options I could try - the XElement is parsed in from a string, so I could do a string replace before it's parsed, but this feels very inelegant. Alternatively, I could traverse the entire document with a depth-first search, using the FirstNode and NextNode properties of the XElement class, but this also feels very inefficient and would negatively impact performance, especially for very large XML documents.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do it recursively?

Comment: First of all, `xmlns` is not an attribute, it is a namespace declaration. You can't just delete the namespace in the DOM, you have to change the namespace of the element.

Answer (score 0):

This should fetch you all the attributes:

```
List<XAttribute> attributes = xml.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
    .Where(attr => attr.Name.LocalName == "xmlns" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that namespace declarations are not just ordinary attributes: they affect the names of elements and attributes, which are two-part names comprising a namespace URI and a local part. Different tree model representations of XML all handle this a bit differently, but the key thing to note is that you don't just want to remove namespace declarations, you want to change the element names.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution leveraging LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

It is an improvement on the @FortyTwo answer. All credit goes to @FortyTwo.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XElement xelem = XElement.Parse(@"<header xmlns='some uri'>
            <tag1 xmlns='another uri'>
                <tag2>
                    <tag3>a value</tag3>
                    <tag4 attr='foo'>bar</tag4>
                    <tag5>something else</tag5>
                    <tag6 xmlns='a third uri'>another value</tag6>
                </tag2>
            </tag1>
            <emptyNsTag xmlns=' ' attr2='something different' attr3='0'>not important</emptyNsTag>
        </header>");

    xelem.DescendantsAndSelf()
        .Attributes()
        .Where(attr => attr.Name.LocalName == "xmlns" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr.Value))
        .ToList()
        .Remove();
        
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);
}
```

**Output**

```
<header xmlns="some uri">
  <tag1 xmlns="another uri">
    <tag2>
      <tag3>a value</tag3>
      <tag4 attr="foo">bar</tag4>
      <tag5>something else</tag5>
      <tag6 xmlns="a third uri">another value</tag6>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <emptyNsTag attr2="something different" attr3="0" xmlns=" ">not important</emptyNsTag>
</header>
```